# Possible to use getIdentifier with incomplete String name?

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of `Buttons`, and I want to get the `Identifier` of these Buttons automatically. Normally I set the `id` like this:

- LayoutButton1
- LayoutButton2
- LayoutButton3
- LayoutButton4

and I get the `Button` id with:

```
getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
```

`name` is a string which contains `"LayoutButton" + number.toString()`. Since I want to give the `Identifier` names a little more meaning, I would like to name buttons like this:

- **Start**LayoutButton1
- **Stop**LayoutButton2

Now I can only get the `id` with

```
getIdentifier("StartLayoutButton1", "id", getPackageName())
```

Is it possible to match the names with a wildcard, as such:

```
getIdentifier("*LayoutButton1", "id", getPackageName())
```

Where the `*` represents any string. In the `id` class within the `R` class will be a variable called `StartLayoutButton1`.

And now I want to get the variable which contains `LayoutButton1` and an unknown prefix.

Comment: getIdentifier(yourVariable + "LayoutButton1", "id", getPackageName());

Comment: Hi, not what i was searching for sorry... I edit my question

Comment: Why would you need any string before "LayoutButton"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it's helpfull for coding when I have another string before LayoutButton to identify the Buttons. When I read StartLayoutButton in the xml File I get a general Idea what this Button is doing...
I know I also just could read the "Text" but I think that is inconvenient.
I don't know if it'll be helpfull but I was curious if it is even possible

Comment: But `getIdentifier()` only returns one ID, how would you return several IDs if you're using a wildcard?

Comment: No it's not possible, it doesn't even make sense. If you're going to use `*LayoutButton1` then this will match all of those buttons. In this case, which id should the `getIdentifier()` method return?

Comment: *LayoutButton1 is only once in the id class.
I want to have it like that:
AnystringLayoutButton1
AnyotherstringLayoutButton2

There will be no other Button
SomestringLayoutButton1

LayoutButton1 is unic it won't be included in any other id Name!